# Step through controls fail to see second dropdown

Tags: vb.net, controls, containers

I have an ASP.net table.  In several cells I have two dropdown lists.  The item selected in each dropdownlist is supposed to be populated from an SQLServer 2005 database.  To do this in my code behind I step through the controls in each table cell.  The code sees the first dropdown and populates it and then goes to the next cell.

My ASP

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="rowEnglish">
    <asp:TableCell ID="celCourseEnglish" runat="server">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourseEnglish" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">English</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCommentEnglish" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Small" DataSourceID="sqlDS_comment" DataTextField="comment" DataValueField="id" Width="125px">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

my VB

```
For Each rowTemp In dtScores.Rows
    Dim tblRow As TableRow
    For Each tblRow In tblProgReport.Rows
        Dim celTemp As New TableCell
            For Each celTemp In tblRow.Cells
                Dim ctl As Control
                    For Each ctl In celTemp.Controls

                        If TypeOf ctl Is DropDownList Then
                        Dim ddlTemp As DropDownList = CType(ctl, DropDownList)
                        'select value from dropdown list
```

I've tried changing the order of the controls in the cell, with the course dropdown still being the one seen.  Tried removing the course dropdown and then the comment dropdown displays correctly.  The whole thing is in a content placeholder from a master page.  Not sure why the second dropdown is not being seen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to post your complete VB code.  What are you doing once you find it?  You are continuing in your foreach correct?  You are not breaking out of it?

Comment: Actually, I had a validation check that the ctl.ID was not nothing.  Picked up some non-IDed control on the next loop through and that kicked it out of the loop.  Thanks.